# Using program's output array as input without parsing

Tags: java, parsing, output

When I run my program the output is an array of triples, or a matrix. I can of course write it in Java syntax into a file. But is there a way in Java to use that array/matrix when I run a java program without having to parse it? Would I have to import it into my source folder? How can I do that?

For example when I write this into a file:

```
int[][] assignment = {{0,1,2},
                      {2,5,0},
                      {4,1,5},
                      {0,3,3}}
```

how can I use the variable "assignment" without having to parse and build a new matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)

```
double[][] outPutArray = {{1.,2.,3},{1.,2.,3.},{1.,2.,3.}}; 
Matrix c = new Matrix(array); 
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c.getArray()));
```